# Calculate duration in sec of wave PCM file with it size

Tags: c#

i want to calculate duration of wave PCM file in sec with C# i found this https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/ link that describe wave file header i use this but this method will not return correct answer

```
public static int GetDuration(this byte[] waveFile)
{
     int bitRate = BitConverter.ToInt32(waveFile, 28) * 8;
     int sampleRate = BitConverter.ToInt32(waveFile, 24);
     int headerSize = 36;
     short channels = BitConverter.ToInt16(waveFile, 22);
     return ((waveFile.Length - headerSize) / (sampleRate * (bitRate / 8))) / channels;
}
```

Comment: public static int GetDuration(this byte[] waveFile) {
        return waveFile.Length / BitConverter.ToInt32(waveFile, 28);
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a 32 bit number which contains the average number of bytes per second at offset `0x1C`. Just divide the length of the `file - 0x2C` by the `average bytes per second`. Take a look at this: http://s14.directupload.net/images/140428/7suewylj.png (from wikipedia).

This method should work for most of the wave files out there.